# Setup Orthographic projection correctly?

Tags: opengl, glm-math, orthographic

Recently I need to use orthographic projection using glm library. But with orthographic projection my scene is not rendering at the center of my viewport.

My Scene is simply a cube, It was rendering well by using glm::perspective. I don't understand too much mathematical stuff, I just using glm::ortho function.

So how do I need to do to correctly setup the orthographic projection?

Here is the code I did:

```
mat4 projection=ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f,-1000.0f, 1000.0f);
mat4 view=lookAt(vec3(0,0,1),vec3(0,0,0),vec3(0,1,0));
mat4 model=mat4();
```

Then I sent these three matrices to shader which is same as perspective projection did.It should be a quad in the center of my screen, but in my program it is lied on the top left corner of the screen,turns out like the a quarter.

Comment: Which coordinates does your cube have?

Answer (score 8):

Your cube appears in the top-left corner of the screen because that's the origin `(0,0,0)` of the coordinate space specified by your orthographic projection.

With your previous perspective projection you probably had an origin at the center of the screen. You can get back to that by changing the values in your orthographic projection:

```
ortho(-(800.0f / 2.0f), 800.0f / 2.0f, 
        600.0f / 2.0f, -(600.0f / 2.0f), 
      -1000.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Comment: I got it, you are totally right. The glm::ortho function should take parameters using: -(screenwidth/2) as left, and screenwidth/2 as right,half screen height as bottom and -(screenheight/2) as top.